# Track if notification was fired

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this:

```
import SwiftUI  
import UserNotifications  

struct ContentView: View {  

    var body: some View {  
        VStack {  
            Button("Request Permission") {  
                RequestNotificationsAccess()  
            }  

            Button("Schedule Notification") {  
                ScheduleNotification()  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  

func RequestNotificationsAccess() {  
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in  
        if success {  
            print("All set!")  
        } else if let error = error {  
            print(error.localizedDescription)  
        }  
    }  
}  

func ScheduleNotification() {  
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()  
    content.title = "Title:"  
    content.subtitle = "some text"  
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default  

    // show this notification five seconds from now  
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)  

    // choose a random identifier  
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)  

    // add our notification request  
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)  
}
```

It works great but when I click multiple times on the button, the notification appears multiple times, how can I track if it was fired already and if so, don't display anything?

Thanks

Comment: you maybe interested in this article https://lmiller1990.github.io/electic/posts/20191007_notifications_in_swift_5_and_ios_13.html

Comment: ok, to make the previous notification not display, try something like this before you schedule another notification:

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() or keep track of the id and use "removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)"

Comment: That works beautiful, thank you. If you want put it on the answer below :) @workingdog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, to make the previous notification not display, try something like this before you schedule another notification:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

or keep track of the id and use

```
removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)"
```